# Pandas: drop values that represent "not applicable"

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset doesn't have any null values. However, when a value in a column is set to 0, it is considered not applicable. Could someone help how can these values be removed? because they are not "null" values, I cannot use the dropna() syntax.

Comment: Please add the code of what your trying to do and the results.

Answer (score 0):

How about a Boolean index?

```py
In [2]: s = pd.Series([0, 1, 1, 0, 2])

In [3]: s[s != 0]
Out[3]:
1    1
2    1
4    2
dtype: int64
```

Note that this does not actually delete the 0 values from the dataset, but it may be sufficient depending on your goals.

If you want to actually remove the data, you can do:

```py
In [16]: s.drop(s[s == 0].index)
Out[16]:
1    1
2    1
4    2
dtype: int64
```